# My brand new toshiba fan is very annoying

Tags: fan, toshiba-laptop

My brand new Toshiba P50-C-12Z running i7 5th Gen, 1TB Storage and 16GRAM, the fan spins a lot, even if I open google chrome, or Firefox, and if I watch YouTube video it spins even though the CPU is under 20% total but still spinning and as soon as I stop the video it stops, and if I open new tab it spins very loud, then when the page load it drops.
I have tested with my Intel Pentium laptop and that laptop does not behave like this new laptop.
Just wondering is this a problem to be concerned about given that the laptop is only < 10 days old. or because the fan is designed spin to protect the CPU.
and how do I stop this , would the cooler solve my problem, or should I get new Graphics card.
Not only that, even a if I launch any application, small or big, the fan has to spin, then it drops. its very annoying, 
should I return this laptop to the seller or is it fine.
and one more thing, if you run laptop at high performance plan does the battery spins?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

First off what are your temps--you can use the free utility CoreTemp to find out.

Most modern laptops will spin up the fan only when the temperature reaches a certain threshold.  Otherwise it's off or spinning slowly.  This keeps it quieter and saves on battery.  You may be able to adjust these via the BIOS or a software utility.